# Parent trap visible but not run by subshell

Tags: bash, subshell, command-substitution, bash-trap

*Tested for Bash 5.0.2*

According to the [GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html),

> Bash performs the expansion [of a command substitution] by executing [the] command in a subshell environment

According to [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html):

> when a subshell is entered, traps that are not being ignored are set to the default actions.

---

So when running the following script:

```
function a {
   trap -p EXIT
}

trap "echo 'parent'" EXIT

echo "$(a)"
(a)

trap - EXIT

echo 'exiting'
```

... i would expect an output of:

```
exiting
```

... but instead I get:

```
trap -- 'echo '\''parent'\''' EXIT
trap -- 'echo '\''parent'\''' EXIT
exiting
```

... meaning that the function `a` - eventhough it is being run in a subshell - is seeing the the parent shell's trap commands (via `trap -p`) but not executing them.

---

What is going on here?

Comment: You appear to be using bash 3.2; if anything, later versions of `bash` move in the opposite direction, executing the trap for `echo "$(a)"` *and* `(a)`. (This remains true through the current release, 5.0.3.)

Comment: I tested it for Bash 3.2.57 and Bash 5.0.2. Same result for me.

Comment: Hm, I don't see an inherited trap for `(a)` in 3.2.37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that the traps trigger exactly according to spec. It's just the output from `trap` that's unexpected.

This is a feature in Bash 4.2 ([release notes](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2011-02/msg00012.html)):

```
b.  Subshells begun to execute command substitutions or run shell functions or
    builtins in subshells do not reset trap strings until a new trap is
    specified.  This allows $(trap) to display the caller's traps and the
    trap strings to persist until a new trap is set.
```

Normally, people would take this for granted. Consider this totally unsurprising Bash exchange:

```
bash$ trap
trap -- 'foo' EXIT
trap -- 'bar' SIGINT

bash$ trap | grep EXIT
trap -- 'foo' EXIT
```

Now look at the result in other shells like Dash, Ksh or Zsh:

```
dash$ trap
trap -- 'foo' EXIT
trap -- 'bar' INT

dash$ trap | grep EXIT
(no output)
```

This is perhaps more correct, but I doubt many people would expect it.

Comment: Yes, that's the quoted section in this answer

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be reading an older version of the specification. In the [most recent one](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap),

> When a subshell is entered, traps that are not being ignored shall be set to the default actions, except in the case of a command substitution containing only a single trap command, when the traps need not be altered.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about this. It indicates *some* exception for command substitutions, but the example in the spec doesn't really match the current case, and it also doesn't explain why `(a)` inherits the trap as well.